# d3 chart overlays new data, doesn't remove old

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6, css-transitions

I've made a D3 v5 stacked area bar chart.

The initial data plots fine, but when I want to update it, it doesn't transition as expected, but overlays the areas on top of each other.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/bental/pen/NMygyB

The main issue lies in this function, with the way I'm dealing with the enter/update/exiting of data:

```
function plotArea(update) {
    const stack = d3.stack();
    stack.keys(keys);
    stack.order(d3.stackOrderReverse);

    const area = startFromZero => {
        const highestVal = getHighestValueForYAxis();
        return d3
            .area()
            .x(d => graphAxes.x(d.data.interval))
            .y0(d => (startFromZero ? highestVal : graphAxes.y(d[0])))
            .y1(d => (startFromZero ? highestVal : graphAxes.y(d[1])));
    };

    if (update) {
        dataPath
            .data(stack(data))
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', d => 'data-path type-' + d.key);
    } else {
        dataPath = svg
            .selectAll('.data-path')
            .data(stack(data))
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', d => 'data-path type-' + d.key);
    }

    dataPath.exit().remove();

    line = dataPath
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'area')
        .attr('d', area(true))
        .transition()
        .delay(200)
        .duration(700)
        .attr('d', area(false));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the update pattern, but here's a solution that removes the old layers and replaces with a new.  I tried doing something with a proper d3 update idiom but the scales for the area paths didn't seem to update properly. Anyhow, here's a working version: https://codepen.io/mortonanalytics/pen/pVaKVd

Comment: Hi @RyanMorton thanks for that, am I right in thinking you just added
    `svg.selectAll('.data-path').remove();`? If so I'm sure the areas are transitionable, but will use this if all else fails.